# Functors in a Small Category

Tags: category-theory

I just came across the following statement while learning Category Theory:

If $\mathcal{C}$ is a small category, then any functor $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$ may be expressed as a colimit in $[C, \mathbf{Set}]$ of a diagram of shape $(\mathbf{1}\downarrow F)^{op}$ whose vertices are representable functors, where $\mathbf{1}$ denotes a singleton set.

I can't seem to find a proof for it anywhere, does anyone know how to prove this?

Comment: This is the "co-Yoneda lemma." See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/co-Yoneda+lemma

Comment: The comma category you refer to is better known as the [category of elements](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+of+elements) of $F$.

Comment: Personally, as somewhat done on the page Qiaochu Yuan mentions, I like to split the result into a result about weighted colimits and another result representing [weighted colimits via the category of elements](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/end#SetCoendsAsColimits). The weighted colimit/coend approach gives a clean, generalizable result, while the reduction of weighted colimits to conical colimits over the category of elements is a bit of a fluke of $\mathbf{Set}$ and usually gives a more cumbersome formula to work with.